# Issue Regarding Base Numbers or Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm an extremely basic java user. I'm doing it for this class, and I've written the entire program, I just can't for the life of me figure out the algorithm that I need to get the desired output, so I was wondering if any Java or Math gurus can help a simple fellow like myself out.  The assignment is due tomorrow and this is the final question.  Any help is appreciated.

This is the code in my main method with the desired output commented in, followed by the sequence 2 method.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     System.out.print(sequence2(i) + "   "); // 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14  
  }



      public static int sequence2(int n) {
   if(n == 0)
       return 1;
   if(n == 1)
       return 2;
   if(n == 2)
       return 4;
   if(n == 3)
       return 5;

    return sequence(n-3) + sequence(n-3);}
```

I'm not sure if it's an issue with my bases, or with my calculation at the bottom.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: So how should the output be evaluated if `n` is more than 3?  You haven't really explained what the rule for the sequence is.

Comment: Sorry, I was unsure of that as well.  My professor didn't offer any type of advice or anything.  He basically just said we need to create a program that outputs the comment.  That was all he said, I can display the entire program, I wasn't sure if that was necessary or not

Also here's the complete question : Write a RECURSIVE method called “sequence2” that takes a single int parameter (n) and returns the int value of the nth element of the sequence S2.  You will need to determine any base cases and a recursive case that describes the listed sequence.

Comment: So, in what way would `System.out.println("// 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14");` be an inadequate solution?

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question, sorry I'm kinda slow with all this stuff.

Comment: Well, why don't you have a good look at that sequence and see if you can figure what the rule might be?  Once you know what it is you're trying to code, you may or may not need more help from the community here.

Comment: I know the rule is +1, +2, +1, +2, but I'm unsure of how to code that into my program.  I'm just looking to be pushed in the right direction.

Comment: OK, well that's a start.  So one thing you could do is to make a loop that prints a number, then adds one, then adds two, then repeats.

Comment: As you have a sequence where every even number has to be handled different than every odd number, you maybe should take a look at the **modulo** `%` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Since it has to be a recursive method, this will do it:

```
public static int sequence2(int n) {
    return (n <= 1 ? n + 1 : 3 + sequence2(n - 2));
}
```

**Original Answer**

This will do it:

```
public static int sequence2(int n) {
    return n / 2 * 3 + n % 2 + 1;
}
```

*Output*

```
1   2   4   5   7   8   10   11   13   14
```

To see how it adds up, here are the intermediate values:

```
n           0   1   2   3   4   5    6    7    8    9
-----------------------------------------------------
n / 2       0   0   1   1   2   2    3    3    4    4

n / 2 * 3   0   0   3   3   6   6    9    9   12   12
n % 2       0   1   0   1   0   1    0    1    0    1
1           1   1   1   1   1   1    1    1    1    1
=====================================================
result      1   2   4   5   7   8   10   11   13   14
```

Comment: That gives the desired output but it needs to be a recursive method, sorry I forgot to mention that!